# Mongodb basics from php to node.js

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

All over the net i cant find a good tutorial for mongodb basics with node.js - socket.io
So my question is:

1. An example for inserting into mongodb with node.js-socket.io
2. Update the records
3. Take from mongo database so

in php/mysql is:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) 
VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

How this code looks like in mongoDB/node.js-socket.io

Comment: some site for mongodb/node.js like w3school for php/mysql ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page contains some simple examples which I've tried out a while back.

http://howtonode.org/node-js-and-mongodb-getting-started-with-mongojs